# Get the data from excel files in sub directories

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and to programming in general. This is my first post on this board. I've been working on this for a while modifying code I've found on the internet and I have the code to do what I want, however I would like to modify it slightly to speed up the process.

The code I have pulls data from excel files that I deposit in a folder on my desktop "Receiving Temp" and places the data in a workbook "Receiving Data Extractor". I am getting data from about 1000 files a month which are stored in sub-directories that are named for the P.O. they are associated with (varying names). Right now I have to go through each of these sub directories and move the excel files to "Receiving Temp" before the Macro will work. I would like to modify the code to do the same with all excel files contained within sub directories within the folder allowing me to just copy the sub-folders into the "receiving temp" folder and run the macro rather than opening each sub directory and grabbing the excel file and moving it manually. Again, the sub-directories have varying names.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

```
Sub ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder()
    Dim FolderName As String, wbName As String, r As Long
    Dim cValue As Variant, bValue As Variant, aValue As Variant
    Dim dValue As Variant, eValue As Variant, fValue As Variant
    Dim wbList() As String, wbCount As Integer, i As Integer

    FolderName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Receiving Temp\"

    ' create list of workbooks in foldername
    wbCount = 0
    wbName = Dir(FolderName & "\" & "*.xls")
    While wbName <> ""
        wbCount = wbCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve wbList(1 To wbCount)
        wbList(wbCount) = wbName
        wbName = Dir
    Wend
    If wbCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    ' get values from each workbook
    r = 1

    For i = 1 To wbCount
        r = r + 1
        cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "c9")
        bValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "o61")
        aValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "ae11")
        dValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "v9")
        eValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "af3")
        fValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Non Compliance", "a1")


         Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1).Value = cValue
         Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2).Value = bValue
         Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3).Value = aValue
         Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 4).Value = dValue
         Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 6).Value = eValue
         Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 5).Value = fValue
     Next i
End Sub

Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, _
wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
    Dim arg As String

    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ""

    If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"

    If Dir(wbPath & "\" & wbName) = "" Then Exit Function

    arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
          wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)

    On Error Resume Next
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

Comment: this should get you in the right direction :) http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=245

Comment: This looks like it will help. Thank you very much.

Comment: I just tested the code and it returns a list of the files that I want to get the data from. However I'm at a loss as to how to apply the code to my existing code to get it to perform the "getinfofromclosedworkbooks" procedure on that list of files. I appreciate your help. Could you please advise on how this might work. Thanks

Comment: Ok gimme 10 mins. I will update it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of the array that you are doing has to be inside the `ProcessFiles` function which is taken from [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=245). Once the array is made, rest of your original code ALMOST remains as it is. I had to make changes to `GetInfoFromClosedFile` function as well so when you copy, copy the complete code given below as it is and do not change anything.

```
Option Explicit

Dim wbList() As String
Dim wbCount As Long

Sub ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder()
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim cValue As Variant, bValue As Variant, aValue As Variant
    Dim dValue As Variant, eValue As Variant, fValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long

    FolderName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Receiving Temp"

    ProcessFiles FolderName, "*.xls"

    If wbCount = 0 Then Exit Sub

    r = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(wbList)

        '~~> wbList(i) will give you something like
        '   C:\Receiving Temp\aaa.xls
        '   C:\Receiving Temp\FOLDER1\aaa.xls
        Debug.Print wbList(i)

        r = r + 1
        cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "c9")
        bValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "o61")
        aValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "ae11")
        dValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "v9")
        eValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "af3")
        fValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Non Compliance", "a1")

        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1).Value = cValue
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2).Value = bValue
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3).Value = aValue
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 4).Value = dValue
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 6).Value = eValue
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 5).Value = fValue
     Next i
End Sub

'~~> This function was taken from
'~~> http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=245
Sub ProcessFiles(strFolder As String, strFilePattern As String)
    Dim strFileName As String, strFolders() As String
    Dim i As Long, iFolderCount As Long

    '~~> Collect child folders
    strFileName = Dir$(strFolder & "\", vbDirectory)
    Do Until strFileName = ""
        If (GetAttr(strFolder & "\" & strFileName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            If Left$(strFileName, 1) <> "." Then
                ReDim Preserve strFolders(iFolderCount)
                strFolders(iFolderCount) = strFolder & "\" & strFileName
                iFolderCount = iFolderCount + 1
            End If
        End If
        strFileName = Dir$()
    Loop

    '~~> process files in current folder
    strFileName = Dir$(strFolder & "\" & strFilePattern)
    Do Until strFileName = ""
        wbCount = wbCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve wbList(1 To wbCount)
        wbList(wbCount) = strFolder & "\" & strFileName
        strFileName = Dir$()
    Loop

    '~~> Look through child folders
    For i = 0 To iFolderCount - 1
        ProcessFiles strFolders(i), strFilePattern
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbFile As String, _
wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
    Dim arg As String, wbPath As String, wbName As String

    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ""

    wbName = FunctionGetFileName(wbFile)
    wbPath = Replace(wbFile, "\" & wbName, "")

    arg = "'" & wbPath & "\[" & wbName & "]" & _
          wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)

    On Error Resume Next
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function

'~~> Function to get file name from the full path
'~~> Taken from http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/GetExcelFileNameFromPath.htm
Function FunctionGetFileName(FullPath As String)
    Dim StrFind As String
    Dim i As Long

    Do Until Left(StrFind, 1) = "\"
        i = i + 1
        StrFind = Right(FullPath, i)
        If i = Len(FullPath) Then Exit Do
    Loop
    FunctionGetFileName = Right(StrFind, Len(StrFind) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: I am so thankful for your help. However, the code when ran displays a dialogue box asking me to select a file. I navigate to the "Receiving Temp" folder and select a file but nothing happens. Then the program keeps repeating the process endlessly. I want to be able to have it look in the "receiving temp" folder and get data from all excel files contained in that directory including ones located in the sub directories. Again, thank you for your help thus far. I might have not explained myself well enough in the beginning.

Comment: Debug this line `arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)` What do you get? I just tested it an it works

Comment: I'm not sure what excatly you mean by debug the line. When I try to run the code it launches a dialouge box. Is this what happens for you?

Comment: Ok Insert this line `Msgbox arg` before that line `On Error Resume Next` what do you get? If possible upload a screenshot.

Comment: Now it displays a message box that list the one of the files in the "receiving temp" folder and then proceeds to do what it was doing before. I do not know how to upload a screenshot, sorry.

Comment: upload it in www.wikisend.com and share the link here

Comment: Okay, I've uplaoded the file. http://wikisend.com/download/564452/Receiving Data Extractor - Copy.xlsm

Comment: Not the file :) i mean the snapshot. But anyways I will check the file as well.

Comment: I must have missed the "\" by mistake. Add "\" before `"[" & wbName & "]"` like this `"\[" & wbName & "]"`. Now try again. i have updated the code above as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to both of you!! A simple Bing-search led me to this valuable collection of code, which I was able to adapt and apply within a few minutes. Excellent work!

Any other beginner (as myself) wanting to use this code, note the following necessary changes:

```
ProcessFiles FolderName, "*.xls"
```

should be changed to "*.xlsx" for excel2010 files.

In the line:

```
cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "c9")
```

and below the similar lines, the "Quality Rep." should be changed to the sheet names where you want to get data from.
In the line:

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1).Value = cValue
```

and below the "Sheet1" should be changed to the sheet name where you want to put the data.

Apart from that, no changes should be necessary.