# Get data and file name from excel files in sub directories

Tags: excel, vba

I have taken this code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898782/get-the-data-from-excel-files-in-sub-directories) on this site and modified it (not by much) to suit my own needs and it's been working brilliantly. Thanks to siddharth-rout for that.
What it does is pulls information from closed files in a directory tree and lists that information onto its own row.

The one thing I really want to do and can't figure out is also grab the file path and also put that onto the relevant row, eg something like:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 7).Value = gValue 'ie the file name
```

With gValue being the file path and name.

I know that GetInfoFromClosedFile has what I want as the value of wbFile but I don't know how to get that to gValue. My programming skills are very mediocre so please be kind. I know it's not as simple as saying:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 7).Value = wbFile
```

but that's all I want. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

I thank you in advance.

Code I borrowed below:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wbList() As String
Dim wbCount As Long

Sub ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder()
Dim FolderName As String
Dim cValue As Variant, bValue As Variant, aValue As Variant
Dim dValue As Variant, eValue As Variant, fValue As Variant
Dim i As Long, r As Long

FolderName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Receiving Temp"

ProcessFiles FolderName, "*.xls"

If wbCount = 0 Then Exit Sub

r = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(wbList)

    '~~> wbList(i) will give you something like
    '   C:\Receiving Temp\aaa.xls
    '   C:\Receiving Temp\FOLDER1\aaa.xls
    Debug.Print wbList(i)

    r = r + 1
    cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "c9")
    bValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "o61")
    aValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "ae11")
    dValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "v9")
    eValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Quality Rep.", "af3")
    fValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wbList(i), "Non Compliance", "a1")

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1).Value = cValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2).Value = bValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3).Value = aValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 4).Value = dValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 6).Value = eValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 5).Value = fValue
 Next i
End Sub

'~~> This function was taken from
'~~> http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=245
Sub ProcessFiles(strFolder As String, strFilePattern As String)
Dim strFileName As String, strFolders() As String
Dim i As Long, iFolderCount As Long

'~~> Collect child folders
strFileName = Dir$(strFolder & "\", vbDirectory)
Do Until strFileName = ""
    If (GetAttr(strFolder & "\" & strFileName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
        If Left$(strFileName, 1) <> "." Then
            ReDim Preserve strFolders(iFolderCount)
            strFolders(iFolderCount) = strFolder & "\" & strFileName
            iFolderCount = iFolderCount + 1
        End If
    End If
    strFileName = Dir$()
Loop

'~~> process files in current folder
strFileName = Dir$(strFolder & "\" & strFilePattern)
Do Until strFileName = ""
    wbCount = wbCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve wbList(1 To wbCount)
    wbList(wbCount) = strFolder & "\" & strFileName
    strFileName = Dir$()
Loop

'~~> Look through child folders
For i = 0 To iFolderCount - 1
    ProcessFiles strFolders(i), strFilePattern
Next i
End Sub

Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbFile As String, _
wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
Dim arg As String, wbPath As String, wbName As String

GetInfoFromClosedFile = ""

wbName = FunctionGetFileName(wbFile)
wbPath = Replace(wbFile, "\" & wbName, "")

arg = "'" & wbPath & "\[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)

On Error Resume Next
GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function

'~~> Function to get file name from the full path
'~~> Taken from http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/GetExcelFileNameFromPath.htm
Function FunctionGetFileName(FullPath As String)
Dim StrFind As String
Dim i As Long

Do Until Left(StrFind, 1) = "\"
    i = i + 1
    StrFind = Right(FullPath, i)
    If i = Len(FullPath) Then Exit Do
Loop
FunctionGetFileName = Right(StrFind, Len(StrFind) - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably what you need to do is add this line :

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 7).Value = wbList(i)
```

right after these lines :

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1).Value = cValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2).Value = bValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3).Value = aValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 4).Value = dValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 6).Value = eValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 5).Value = fValue
```

Comment: Cheers. I'll give it a try on Monday.